# I went on holiday in 2002 and would like to go back again one day. Could I find out where I went?

Tags: uk, spain

I went to Spain in 2002 but I don't remember the name of the place.

I was 15 and I remember once standing on the balcony of the top floor of our hotel looking at a roller coaster in the distance. It must have been ten miles (~16 km) away and looked like it was on a hill.

In future when/if I decide to renew my passport, or get a new one, would there be any way of finding out where I went, which airline, etc?

Edit: after doing some Googling, searching for roller coasters in Spain, looking at pictures, opening dates, etc, I think it was Stampida, PortAdventura.

But like I say, I didn't go there, I was looking at it in the distance.

Comment: How did you pay for everything?  Do you have access to the credit card statements?

Comment: Hi, I don't know much about it as I just went with my family. I was just 15 and it was in 2002, so as far as anything else goes i don't know. It may have been this place here. https://life-globe.com/en/boulevard-jaime-salou/ - I remember the road had trees like that and tiles on the floor.

Comment: Then I would ask your family if they remember, or if they have any relevant records (diaries, calendars, credit card statements, emails to friends about the trip, etc).  There isn't some universal searchable database keeping tabs on all British travelers to Spain, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: There is a photograph of us stood on a boulevard like that, so I could check all the major boulvards in Salou on Google Maps and see. I just wondered if there was anything related to my passport (the authority that issues it etc) where they know where I last travelled to. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Passport data would at best record the fact that you went to Spain, and maybe the airport where you entered, but it wouldn't have anything about where you actually went within Spain or the Schengen area.

Comment: My guess is no, and even so, I don't see how knowing the airline would help identify the place you actually went.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes that is obvious isn't it, I guess I'd just have to narrow it down to the general road front, boulevard, then try and find that hotel again.

Comment: If you like, you can scan the photo and include it in your question (there's an image button), and add the tag [tag:identify-this].  Some people here are quite good at identifying places from photos.

Comment: Yes I may do that in future, thanks for that, I will have to get my auntie to send it to me again, she has all the photos. Thanks again :)

Comment: You don't need any of this information to renew your passport.

Answer (score 2):

In case it was a wooden roller coaster, the two main options are Stampida in Port Aventura and Magnus Colossus in Terra Mítica. I would bet you were seeing the second one for a couple reasons:

- Terra Mítica has a hill just behind Magnus Colossus. On the other hand, Stampida is in a plain area.
- Benidorm (the closest city to Terra Mítica) has always been crowded with British people. Nowadays, around 30% of all British tourists in Spain go to Benidorm, where they occupy 50% of the available hotel rooms.
- Benidorm has some of the tallest hotels in Spain, so you were probably able to see the distant amusement park from the top floor of one of them. I don't know if this is possible from Cambrils, Salou or any other city near Port Aventura.

Comment: +1 but there is also a lot of British tourists in Salou